# Points always get added to the first person

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json', 'utf8'))
const userUsed = new Set();

var client = new Discord.Client();
const Enmap = require("enmap");
client.points = new Enmap({
  name: "points"
});

//-----------TABLE--------------
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.username}...`)
  console.log(`Bot has started, with ${client.users.size} users, in ${client.channels.size} channels of ${client.guilds.size} guilds.`);
});

//-------------MESSAGE STARTS----------------
client.on("message", (message) => {
      const user = message.mentions.users.first();
      const key = `${message.guild.id}-${message.author.id}`;
      let command = message.content.split(" ")[0];
      command = command.slice(config.prefix.length);

      // ---------------COMMANDS--------------------------------------------------
      if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

      if (command === "loben") {
        if (userUsed.has(message.author.id)) return;
        else {
          let Mas = message.guild.roles.find(Mas => Mas.name === "Master");
          if (message.member.roles.has(Mas.id)) {
            if (user) {
              const member = message.guild.member(user);
              if (member) {
                let Pad = member.guild.roles.find(Pad => Pad.name === "Padawan");
                if (member.roles.has(Pad.id))
                  client.points.ensure(key, {
                    user: message.mentions.users.first().id,
                    guild: message.guild.id,
                    points: 0,
                    level: 1,
                    lastSeen: new Date()
                  });
                client.points.inc(key, "points");
                message.reply(`${user}, ist dem Master einen Schritt näher.`)
              }
            }
            userUsed.add(message.author.id);
            setTimeout(() => {
              (userUsed.delete(message.author.id));
            }, 1000 * 10);
          }
        }
      }
```

This is the command I'm working on.
My Problem is that when I use it for
the first time, the mentioned user gets a point, how it should be. For
example: `+loben @Tom123`, Tom gets 1 point

If I use the command again and mention some other user (for example,
Luke) not Luke gets the point, but Tom does. So Tom has 2 points and
Luke none.

I have no clue why...

Comment: `else` block seems unnecessary after `if (userUsed.has(message.author.id)) return;` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say there are 3 users:

1. Daikota
2. Tom123
3. Luke

Daikota uses command `+loben @Tom123`.

#### What happens?

```
const key = `${message.guild.id}-${message.author.id}`;
```

On this line, `message.author.id` is Daikota's id. For simplicity's sake let's say that `key` evaluates to `"Daikota"`. Then:

```
client.points.ensure(key, {
  user: message.mentions.users.first().id,
  guild: message.guild.id,
  points: 0,
  level: 1,
  lastSeen: new Date()
});
client.points.inc(key, "points");
```

According to [enmap documentation](https://enmap.evie.codes/api#enmap-ensure-key-defaultvalue), `enmap.ensure(key, defaultvalue)` makes sure the key exists in the Enmap. If it doesn't exist, `enmap.ensure` creates it and sets its value as default value you pass to the method. In our example it would be something like this:

```
{
  "Daikota": {
    user: "Tom123",
    points: 0,
    // etc
  }
}
```

Then using `client.points.inc(key, "points");` makes sure that it gets `points` of `"Daikota"` and increases it by 1. After this operation our Enmap looks something like this:

```
{
  "Daikota": {
    user: "Tom123",
    points: 1,
    // etc
  }
}
```

#### Next step

Daikota uses command `+loben @Luke`

Then again, `message.author.id` is Daikota. `enmap.ensure` will take our `"Daikota"` key and see that it's already inside our Enmap, so it won't create new. Then after `client.points.inc(key, "points");` line, our Enmap probably looks something like this:

```
{
  "Daikota": {
    user: "Tom123",
    points: 2,
    // etc
  }
}
```

Which seems to be what you describe.

#### Solution

Use mentioned user id instead of message's author id as a key for Enmap in your case.